# No duplicate in call log listview

Tags: android, sqlite, logging, call

Call log listview screen shot as i have got right now

I just don't want duplicate values in my database. So that one contact name will be displayed single time in my listview and also I want number of calls associated with its number. I may get unique value by using unique keyword while inserting in database through query but i don't have any about counting a calls I get from that number.

I am using following code to get call logs from database. Right now I am just accessing the call logs and displaying it. I have not stored in database.I just won't an idea how to count number of calls from particular number and show it in front it.As it is displayed in call logs applications.

```
      Cursor callLogCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    if (callLogCursor != null) {
        while (callLogCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
            String name = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
            String cacheNumber = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL));
            String number = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            long dateTimeMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
            long durationMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
            int callType = callLogCursor.getInt(callLogCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));

            String duration = getDuration(durationMillis * 1000);

            String dateString = getDateTime(dateTimeMillis);


            if (cacheNumber == null)
                cacheNumber = number;
            if (name == null)
                name = "";
            Uri image = null;

            try {
                String conId = fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(cacheNumber);
                long contId = Long.parseLong(conId);
                image = getPhotoUri(contId);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }


                CallLogModel callLogModel = new CallLogModel(image, name, cacheNumber,
                        duration, dateString);


            if (callType == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
                outgoingList.add(callLogModel);

            } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE) {
                incomingList.add(callLogModel);

            } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
                missedcallList.add(callLogModel);

            }

        }

        callLogCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i'll..but i didn't added anything to get number of calls assciated with a particular number.

Comment: Use distinct keyword this will return unique record from database.

db.rawQuery("Select DISTINCT from table_name",null);

Comment: Yes. But we do need your current code in order to help you.

Comment: add new field `numCall` in model and check if record is already exist then just find (no need to add) index of that model in list and increase `numCall` by 1.

Comment: @Ketan sorry i didn't get..please elaberate

Comment: `I may get unique value by using unique keyword while inserting in database through query`. now if you can identify each unique data then add one new field (numCall) and check if particular record is duplicate then just find it and increase numCall for that record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using group by clause as following:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { CallLog.Calls._ID, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI_CALL, columns, null, null, null);
```